# catch separated fails using deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I got this code (using jquery)

```
function getData(applyFunction, callback) {
$.when(
    $.getJSON("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59d72b5b120000c902cb1b4f"),
    $.getJSON("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59d72b5b120000c902cb1b4f"),
).done(function(
    firstData,
    secondData
){
    callback(applyFunction, {
        firstDataToApply: { data: firstData.popup },
        secondDataToApply: { data: secondData.popup }
    })
})
}
```

Is there a way to catch separate errors from the `$.getJSON` part(or the `when` part), log those errors, and still be able to send both  `firstData` and `secondData`(at the same time) to the callback function?

(I'm aware that if some or both `$.getJSON` fail I'd be sending empty data to the callback, and would have to null check before getting popup)

sorry for the confusing post, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Promises are pipelines and each handler in the pipeline can transform the value or error passing through, so you can turn a failure into a "success with `null`" if that's really want you want to do by adding a `catch` handler and returning `null` (or whatever value you want to transform the error into) from it. See the `catch` calls below and also the comments:

```
function getData(applyFunction, callback) {
    $.when(
        $.getJSON("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59d72b5b120000c902cb1b4f")
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.error(err);
                return null;
            }),
        $.getJSON("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59d72b5b120000c902cb1b4f")
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.error(err);
                return null;
            })
    ).done(function(firstData, secondData) {
        callback(applyFunction, {
            firstDataToApply: {
                data: firstData.popup    // You'll need checks on this!
            },
            secondDataToApply: {
                data: secondData.popup   // And this!
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Of course, if you're going to do this more than once or twice, you can avoid repeating yourself with a function:

```
function getJSONOrNull(url) {
    return $.getJSON(url).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return null;
    });
}
```

then

```
function getData(applyFunction, callback) {
    $.when(
        getJSONOrNull("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59d72b5b120000c902cb1b4f"),
        getJSONOrNull("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59d72b5b120000c902cb1b4f")
    ).done(function(firstData, secondData) {
        callback(applyFunction, {
            firstDataToApply: {
                data: firstData.popup    // You'll need checks on this!
            },
            secondDataToApply: {
                data: secondData.popup   // And this!
            }
        });
    });
}
```